How do you retain/“re-add” all leading zero(es) in a String of length 9 (that is truncated when being converted from a Long)?
So, question:
How would I “re-add” all leading zero(es) in a String of length 9 (that is truncated when being converted from a Long)?
More details:
In the “front-end” (API), the String value sent in is of length 9, :
e.g. “000000000”, “000000001”, “000000010”
Request body:
{
    someObjects: [
        someObject1:    {
            Id: “000000000”;
        ],
        someObject2:    {
            Id:  “000000001”
        },
        someObject3:    {
            Id:  “000000010”
        }
}

The corresponding java class is:
class SomeObject {
    Long id;
}

In the handler method:
public void someRequestHandlerMethod(List<SomeObject> someObjects) {
    for(SomeObject someObject : someObjects) {
        Long Id = someObject.getId();
        LOGGER.info(“Id is: ”+Id);
    }
}

What is happening, is if a number starts with zero(es), when it is converted to a Long, all the zero(es) in front of the remaining number are getting truncated.  e.g.
“000000000” becomes “0”
“000000001” becomes “1”
“000000010” becomes “10”
and so forth.
So it prints out:
Id is: 0 (instead of Id is: 000000000).
Id is: 1 (instead of Id is: 000000001).
Id is: 10 (instead of Id is: 000000010).

Question:  How would I retain the zero(es) or “re-add” them using String manipulation,  so that it prints out like:
“000000000” is printed out as “000000000” and not as “0”
“000000001” is printed out as “000000001” and not as “1”
“000000010” is printed out as “000000010” and not as “10”.

Basically, retaining or “re-adding” all leading zero(es) in a number String of lenth 9?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
thank you so much!

Not practicable. Numbers know nothing about leading zeros. You could only store the original somewhere else - impractical. The alternative would be to model the ID as a string in the first place

If you want a String, use a String.

Prefer long to Long and use id (not Id, that's a class name). String.format("%09d", id)

Why use a String?  Why not make the id a long to start with and not worry about conversions?

Based on Ellioth Frisch's comment and assuming that the class SomeObject does not have other attributes, try this:
public record SomeObject( long id )
{
  @Override
  public final String toString() { return "%09d".formatted( id ); }
}

Your loop would then look this this:
public final void someRequestHandlerMethod( final List<SomeObject> someObjects ) 
{
  for( final var someObject : someObjects ) 
  {
    LOGGER.info( “Id is: %s”.formatted( someObject ) );
  }
}

Of course to can also add a method getId() to SomeObject:
…
public final String getId() { return  "%09d".formatted( id ); }
…

and leave toString() untouched. Then you do not have to change your code at all. To get the value of id as long, the record still provides the method id().
